# Not Getting Promise status as rejected

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. I was working with Promise in JS where I encountered the below. Please help me understand this.

Even if the reject() is getting called, I am still getting the status of Promise as fulfilled only. I am not able to understand why this is happening.

Here is the code:

```
    const willGetGamingPC = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const randNum = Math.random();
        if(randNum <= 0.5)
            reject();
        else
            resolve();
    }, 3000)
})
.then(() => console.log("Here is your Gaming PC"))
.catch(() => console.log("Unfortunately no Gaming PC for you"));
```

"Unfortunately no Gaming PC for you" is getting printed but when I am checking the status of Promise after that, it is showing as Fulfilled.

[image]

Comment: `willGetGamingPC` is not the `new Promise` itself, but the return value of the `.catch(…)` call - which is a separate promise, resolved with the return value of the `catch` handler.

Comment: Thanks Bergi for your response, it was quite helpful.